# Angular 2 global service provider

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am new to angular 2.I have defined my service in the shared folder and added these services in the app.module.js provider section. I am using Behavioral Subject to save user state. When I logged in I update my Behavioral Subject with the user and showing the user name in the side bar template. But when I refresh my page or press ctrl+r then Behavioral Subject goes back to the empty user and in the side bar template my user name disappears. My Behavioral Subject is not maintaining its value when I refresh the page or press ctrl+r. I am get stucked here kinldly guide me whats the problem here

```
UserService:-

private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());

public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

loginUser(email, password): Observable<User> {
        const route = '/login'
        return this.apiService.post('/user' + route, {email, password})
            .map(
                data => {
                    this.saveUser(data.user);
                    return data;
                }
            );
    }

saveUser(user: User) {
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
}

In SideBarComponent:--

export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {
user: User;
constructor(private userService: UserService,
                private router: Router) {

        this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(
            (userData) => {
                this.user = userData;
            }
        )
    }
}

app.module.ts:

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
        SidebarModule,
        NavbarModule,
        FooterModule,
        SharedModule,

    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminLayoutComponent,
        AuthLayoutComponent,
    ],

    providers: [UserService],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

when we refresh the page angular bootstrap application due to this my singleton initialized again. Because of that my behavior subject lost data.